# Exception handling with python subprocess.run

Tags: python, databricks

I am new to Python. I need to catch all the error / exceptions from subprocess.run.

Currently, I have a Python file which has subprocess.run(**shell script**) [ runs a shell script ]

I need to catch all the exceptions from this process,

I tried except '**Exception as e: print(e)**' but couldn't see all the errors.

Answer (score 8):

According to doc [subprocess.check_output()_doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), you can handle the exception as follow:

```
try:
    subprocess.run(...)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print e.output
```

Answer (score 6):

Use check_returncode() like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

try:
    ls = subprocess.run( ("ls", "-w"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE )
    ls.check_returncode()
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print ( "Error:\nreturn code: ", e.returncode, "\nOutput: ", e.stderr.decode("utf-8") )
    raise

print ( ls.stdout.decode("utf-8") )
```

This runs "ls -w", which returns an error (-w requires an argument), triggers the exception handling, prints the return code and stderr output, and re-raises the exception. If you try it with "ls -l" instead, it will run the command successfully and print its output.